# Power problems related to copper wires and pigtails

Tags: power-supply, wire, copper

I am using a battery to power a odroid which requires 5V/4A. The battery voltage when measured using a multimeter was around 26.7.

I had two setups:

1. I used a 1 sq mm copper current carrying wire to connect between the battery and dc converter (24V-5V) and a pigtail to power the odroid and it worked.
2. In this one I had replaced the 1 mm sq copper wire with a 2.5 mm sq copper wire but the board doesn't seem to get started.

Is their anything I had missed out regarding the copper wires in the 2nd setup?

Comment: Have you tried a multimeter?

Comment: yeah, i did check the voltage of the pigtail and it was 5V but for some reason it keeps rebooting.

Comment: Add some details about the DC-DC converter to your question. A link to the datasheet perhaps.